# Cowsay doesn't say anything

Tags: macos, terminal, github, gem

Okay, I know this is kind of a stupid question to bring to the table here... but why not.

I'm using OS X 10.9.2, Mavericks, and have installed cowsay in my terminal with `$ sudo gem install cowsay` and it said everything installed properly.

However, when I run `$ cowsay`, the little dudes don't ever say anything!

Here's some pics of the problem.
[image: Pic 1]
[image: Pic 2]
[image: Pic 3]
[image: Pic 4]

So can someone tell me...

How to configure `cowsay` so I can select which critters I wantto see? "

How to give them something to say?

The command to make each new terminal start with `cowsay` if the section of the OS X
Terminal where you can specify a start-up command doesn't work?
Is there a github repo where I can download new phrases and critters?

Any info you guys can provide me so I can enjoy these little critters more whenever Terminal starts up will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 7):

You have to pipe the text you want to have "said by the cow"

```
echo "hello world" | cowsay
```

Another cool thing to do is mixing cowsay and fortune

```
fortune | cowsay
```

Comment: do I need to install another gem for fortune to work?

Comment: yes you need to install it : 
osx : sudo port install fortune
ubuntu : sudo apt-get install fortune

Answer (score 1):

You can also type 
`cowsay "The text you want to say"`