# CowSay (apt-get moo) for OS X?

Tags: linux, macos, apt-get

I used Linux before I got a Mac and I remember moo cow "Have you mooed today?" from apt-get moo. I've got some time to kill and am tired. I'm waiting for my hotel room to be available and was wondering if I could get that on a mac via curl or home-brew.

Comment: https://github.com/tadeuzagallo/mac-moo

Comment: That just prints out "Have you mooed today" (judging by the script). I was looking for the one with the command line arguments ex "cowsay test" would make the cow say test

Comment: I guess it would be this instead: http://superuser.com/questions/730395/cowsay-doesnt-say-anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install it two ways. One is using Homebrew:

```
$ brew install cowsay
```

The second is downloading and compiling it yourself:

```
$ wget http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/cdimage/snapshot/Debian/pool/main/c/cowsay/cowsay_3.03.orig.tar.gz
$ tar xf cowsay_3.03.orig.tar.gz
$ cd cowsay-3.03
$ ./install.sh
```